# class instance changed in callback method comparing to the main instance

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

in cpp:

```
void Character::jump(CCLayer *layer){
    if (this->isAnimationPlaying) return;
    up_or_down = UP;
    body->runAction(CCSequence::actions(
                                        CCMoveBy::actionWithDuration(0.5, ccp(0, 50)),
                    CCCallFuncND::actionWithTarget(body, callfuncND_selector(Character::upDownDone), this),
//                                        CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget(body, callfuncN_selector(Character::upDownDone)),
                    NULL));
    this->isAnimationPlaying = true;
}

void Character::upDownDone(CCNode *node, CCObject *ob){
   this->isAnimationPlaying = false;   // *this is different from the this(class instance) in jump method, seems this in upDownDone is a new created instance*
}
```

So How can I get the class instance in a callback method? And can I make the this same for the main class instance and the callback's class instance?

EDIT:

Character is a class which has no parent class, and body is a member variable which is an instance of CCSprite.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it might be better to make Character a subclass of CCNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using `body` to call the function `Character::upDownDone`.

you should use `this` to call it.

```
CCCallFuncND* callFunc = CCCallFuncND::actionWithTarget(first_arg, secend_arg, third_arg);
body->runAction(callFunc);
```

assume your `secend_arg` is `callfuncND_selector(Character::upDownDone)`

then,

the `first_arg` is the caller, ie.  the class instance who calls this function, in your code is `body`. but actually it should be `this`, or any instance of Charactor class

the `CCNode* node` (the first para that is been passed to your calling function) is the action runner, ie. `body` in your code. because you are using `body->runAction()`

the `CCObject* obj` (the second para that is been passed to your calling function) is a void pointer which is exactly the same with `third_arg`.

another way is use

```
void Character::upDownDone(CCNode *node, void *ob){
    (Character*)ob->isAnimationPlaying = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the Character is not a CCNode child class, body is. So I run it against body.

Comment: @TowerJoo then your should change your `void Character::upDownDone(CCNode *node, CCObject *ob)` to `void Character::upDownDone(CCNode *node, void *ob){ (Character*)ob-> isAnimationPlaying = false}`

Comment: @TowerJoo but actually there will be a serious problem, because the body does not have the function Character::upDownDone, how can you run the code? cuz if using your code, if you trace down the source code of cocos2d-x, finally `body->*(&Character::upDownDone)(body, this);` will be excuted.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You're right. I didn't understand the call so well. Now I fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you call the Character::upDownDone method using the instance "body" instead of this .May be you want this:

```
CCCallFuncND::actionWithTarget(this, callfuncND_selector(Character::upDownDone), body),
```